# How to compare files using 010 Editor in Perforce/P4V

Tags: diff, perforce, binaryfiles, p4v

I'm trying to use 010 Editor v8.0.1 as the diff program for binary files in P4V, especially those which I have a template script for (eg, EXEs).

According to the [-compare documentation](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/CommandLine.htm#-compare) on 010's site, the commandline I want to use is `-compare:%1::%2::\e\t`.

I'm using P4V's [assign diff applications by file type](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.3/manuals/p4v/#P4V/configuring.preferences.diff.html%3FTocPath%3DConfiguring%2520P4V%7CConfiguring%2520P4V%2520preferences%7C_____18) using the above code for the arguments value.

The problem is, P4V will *not* replace the positional arguments %1 and %2 when there are non-whitespace characters before and after them. If I put a space before and after P4V will happily replace them with the desired files I want to diff. However, 010 Editor cannot handle this format.

What can I do to solve this incompatibility for Windows systems?

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this incompatibility by creating a .bat file to pipe the P4V provided arguments in a way 010 will happily eat them. Save the below script to a file named `010EditorP4Diff.bat`, then set P4V to diff your desired file extension using this bat script path as the "Application" path and `%1 %2` as the "Arguments" value.

I've also included a way to shortcut launching binary templates based on the first file's extension. As of the latest version of 010 Editor (v8.0.1), the `-template` parameter will only apply to the `%2` file. You will need to manually open the Template Results view (`Alt+4`) 
 and run the desired template (`F5`, select from the list) for the first file.

This of course assumes you have installed the EXE.bt template from the 010 editor repository.

```
REM https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/CommandLine.htm#-compare
echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg1_extension=%~x1
set arg2=%2

REM Sadly, as of 010 v8.0.1, the template only auto shows up for the arg2 file :[
if      %arg1_extension% == ".exe"  goto EXE_TEMPLATE
else if %arg1_extension% == ".dll"  goto EXE_TEMPLATE
else                                goto NO_TEMPLATE

:EXE_TEMPLATE
start 010editor -compare:%arg1%::%arg2%::\e\t -   template:"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SweetScape\010 Templates\Repository\EXE.bt"
goto GETOUT

:NO_TEMPLATE
start 010editor -compare:%arg1%::%arg2%::\e\t
goto GETOUT

:GETOUT
```